# Javascript function not firing on window.onresize

Tags: javascript, onresize

I have created a small script to center a form vertically using js. However, it does not seem to work with window.onresize and I dont understand why.  BTW it works perfect on window.onload and the window.onresize will fire an alert on resize if I ask it to. Here is my code:

```
var resetHeight = function(){

  var loginForm = document.querySelector('.login-form');
  var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
  var topNavbarHeight = document.querySelector('.top-navbar').clientHeight;
  var loginFormHeight = loginForm.clientHeight;
  var footerHeight = document.querySelector('footer').clientHeight;
  var totalHeights = loginFormHeight + topNavbarHeight + footerHeight + 90;
  var halfHeight = (windowHeight-totalHeights) / 2;

  loginForm.style.paddingTop = halfHeight + "px";
  loginForm.style.paddingBottom = halfHeight+ "px";      

};

window.onload = resetHeight;

window.onresize = resetHeight;
```

Comment: Your code should work, doesn't seem to be anything wrong with it, make sure you are adding script before end body tag `</body>` and try wrapping it in a immediately invoked function. something like this https://jsbin.com/rexuvel/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1):

This is a jquery solution I wrote that works (for me). It would be great to have a vanilla javascript answer.

```
var resetHeight = function(){
  var loginForm = $(".login-form");
  var loginFormHeight = loginForm.height();
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  var topNavbarHeight = $('.top-navbar').height();
  var footerHeight = $('footer').height();
  var totalHeights = loginFormHeight + topNavbarHeight + footerHeight + 90;
  var halfHeight = (windowHeight-totalHeights) / 2;
  loginForm.css({
    "padding-top":halfHeight,
    "padding-bottom":halfHeight
  });

} 

  $( document ).ready(function(){
   resetHeight();   
   window.addEventListener('resize', resetHeight);     
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried alerting your required values upon window resize? You should give the JQuery solution a try:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', resetHeight);
```

Also, I would try using the `onresize="resetHeight()"` event listener inside the  tag of your HTML. Let me know if this works!

Comment: I'm afraid the JavaScript only renders the .onresize listener once. If you move it to the <body> tag in HTML, it will render every time the body size is changed.

Comment: This works!!! Any chance of a solution that would get my code to work without jquery? Thanks!!!!!

Comment: Awesome! Did you try the `<body onresize="resetHeight()">` method?

Answer (score 0):

load resize action in body tag like this

```
<body onresize="resetHeight()">
```

Comment: Does not work any different than what I already have but thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but a suggestion, why would you use javascript for this when you can use CSS? It will perform much better and support more people. Here is a simple example of a div that is always centered in it's container:

```css
#centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="centered">

</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion but this does not work for me. Maybe because Im using bootstrap.

Comment: @rod122

Yes, this is the simplest way possible. You probably shouldn't listen to me, but I would also recommend not using bootstrap, especially if your form isn't super complex. It will give you more control and be much cleaner/smaller files. Less divs, less classes, less ids, and more understanding of how these things actually work so you have control. Also, Patching layout with javascript should be avoided at all costs because it is a performance hog and can glitch unexpectedly on different platforms. I think you should try writing it from scratch with as little divs as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using jquery to do this for example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( window ).resize(function() {
   var loginForm = document.querySelector('.login-form');
   var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
   var topNavbarHeight = document.querySelector('.top-navbar').clientHeight;
   var loginFormHeight = loginForm.clientHeight;
   var footerHeight = document.querySelector('footer').clientHeight;
   var totalHeights = loginFormHeight + topNavbarHeight + footerHeight + 90;
   var halfHeight = (windowHeight-totalHeights) / 2;

   loginForm.style.paddingTop = halfHeight + "px";
   loginForm.style.paddingBottom = halfHeight+ "px";  
});

});
```